# How to turn off Mountain Lion's screensaver's password requirement?

Tags: macos, password, screensaver

I have the current version Mountain Lion and set the Screensaver to 30 minutes, but since I am the only person that have access to this computer, I would like to turn the password off, but there seems to be no such method?

Comment: Please, do you use FileVault 2? And what model is the Mac?

Comment: I don't use FileVault... (mine is FileVault, not FireVault 2 on the Mountain Lion)... it is a Mac mini, but does it matter?  I thought Mountain Lion behaves the same no matter what Mac it is

Comment: The check box in the screenshot by @Hoshts is not seen on my computer running Mountain Lion with FileVault enabled. For security, it makes sense for Apple to limit/remove the preference.

Comment: I have FV2 enabled but still see this option in Preferences. Strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under `System Preferences -> Security & Privacy` there is an option to not require password to wake computer from sleep or screen saver.

[image]

Comment: For some users of Mountain Lion, that check box does not exist.

Comment: Depending on hardware I guess?

Comment: I'm not sure. Please see commentary to the opening question. At the time of your screenshot, did you use FileVault 2?

Comment: For anyone who still gets a password screen after unchecking this, it could be because the user you're logging in as isn't an Admin user. To make the user an Admin, go to System Preferences > Users & Groups > click the lock icon > select the user > check "Allow user to administer this computer"

Answer (score 3):

If you turn on FileVault then the checkbox disappears, so your **only** choice is how long it will take before you need to enter a password. I found this so irritating that I turned off FileVault altogether. Then the checkbox came back and I could get rid of that option.

What is also strange here is that when you have FileVault on (and thus have no choice about having to enter a password) the maximum time is 1 hour. When you have it turned off, not only can you turn the password option off altogether, you also have a maximum grace time of 4 hours.